# How can I "abort" auto exposure bracketing after taking the first shot?

Tags: canon-550d, camera-controls, bracketing

When using AEB in the Canon EOS 550D, is there a convenient way to skip the second and third shot after the first one has been made?

I am asking this because I sometimes do long exposure shots using AEB and then notice that the metering was way off after the first shot. It is then rather cumbersome to go into the AEB menu, disable AEB, re-configure it and then shoot again, but when a single exposure takes 5" or longer it's almost faster than just taking the two additional shots.

Comment: Why don't you leave AEB off, take a shot, check the exposure, then only turn AEB on if it looks correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have a 550D to test this out on, but I know on some Canon models I find it most convenient to just turn the camera off then back on. It loses the AEB setting and keeps the rest of the details I am interested in.

This would be directed more at the question of simply how to abort AEB mode, rather then get you quickly back INTO AEB mode step 1.

Comment: I do this all the time on my Nikons as well.

Comment: This works on the 550D. Interesting workaround, wouldn't have thought of it...